# Is it possible to build a Web app with driven user experience but not necessary to send any user data?

Tags: security, privacy

Given the increasing concerns in data privacy, is it possible to build a web app that provides a driven user experience (aka different outcomes on different users based on their specific profiles) without sending any personal information that can be tracked, hijacked or forced by any entity on the web app's servers ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat vague, but due to the fact that HTTP is stateless, you'll need users to send some kind of information, at the very least user registration and login data to identify them and store their identity in some kind of storage (ex. cookie).

If you dont want the users to [post any data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST), you wont be able to personalize the experience, just provide the same experience to everyone every time they enter your website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this, but you will need to identify users at the start, and then unidentify them later - for example, get them to register with an email address, confirm that address, then create an identifier derived from that address (e.g. a hash or random number), switch to using it as a user name and delete the email address. Then you will be at a point where they can log into an account, but you hold no personal identifiers on them.